# Is it possible to implement a Content Delivery Network (CDN) if I'm with a cluster web host?

Tags: performance, cdn

I'm with a webhost, a web farm or cluster, I guess you could say.  I have a 47 page company website, and all speed tests suggest I use a CDN.

I've googled and SE's this to no end, but still don't understand how to implement a content delivery network.  Are they suggesting I order a subdomain and put all my .css, .js, and image files in that subdomain?  Or are they suggesting that instead of downloading jquery 1.7, I just link to malsup's jquery?  But then what would I do for images and .css?

Just kinda confused here; any help in this regard would be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you can implement a CDN with a cluster web host. In the vast majority of cases if you can change your DNS settings you can implement CDN. Another suggestion is to use a cookie-less domain. But, a content delivery network will optimize the delivery of all the files you mentioned. While I'm not sure of all the particulars of your specific setup and situation, it sounds like you could use front-end optimization and an overall faster site delivery. Take a look at the following that highlights EdgeCast's integration of Google's PageSpeed into our content delivery network, and how they'll help out sites like yours in tandem: http://www.edgecast.com/docs/ec-edgeopt-datasheet.pdf